# SVG Sprite with CSS background-size: 100% auto;

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites

Good day.

I am currently building a website and I would like to make the transition from icon fonts to pure svg icons.

The problem is when I try to use my SVG sprite (1:3 width to height ratio) as a background

```
.icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-image: url('path/to.svg');
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

It is scaled down and my hover effect (below) gets awkwardly positioned.

```
.icon:hover,
.icon:focus {
  background-position: 0 -1em;
}
```

It works correctly when I have a sprite sized 1:2 width to height ratio.

Any suggestions?

Sincerely, Sebastian.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: I do not have the project locally at the moment. I will post one tomorrow. @TilwinJoy

Comment: Does your svg have a viewBox and a "slice" preserveAspectRatio attribute?  Otherwise, it will try to scale to fit inside your icon shape.  Or maybe, since it's working for your 1:2 sprite sheet, you just forgot to update the viewBox for the new image?  All just speculation without seeing the code...

Comment: It has the appropriate viewBox, but the preserveAspectRatio I am unsure about. I will post a fiddle tomorrow @AmeliaBR

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" solved it. Thank you @AmeliaBR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
```

This code solved it. Thank you AmeliaBR.

EDIT:

If you are using Adobe Illustrator to export your SVG files, remember to uncheck "Responsive". Otherwise the sprite will not work as intended in Internet Explorer.

Comment: And here's the link to MDN for some further explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio